# xargs argument not interpreted

Tags: shell, sed, xargs

I have a directory `$dir` that contains `.txt.xy` files and subdirectories with `.txt.xy` files. I try to iterate over each file and pass the whole path as well as the path without `$dir` as argument to a program like this:

```
dir="/path/to/"
suffix=".xy"

find "$dir" -name "*.txt.xy" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'program "$1" |
  subprogram filename="$2"' _ {} "$(echo {} | sed -e "s#^${dir}##" -e "s#${suffix}\$##")"
```

- `$1` shold be the full path (e.g. `/path/to/subdir/file.txt.xy`)
- `$2` should be the full path without `$dir` and `$suffix` (e.g. `subdir/file.txt`)

`$1` is the propper full path but `$2` is also the full path as if the pipe in `$(...)` is never executed. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt seems rather roundabout. It sounds like you are looking for

```sh
find /path/to -name "*.txt.xy" -exec sh -c '
    for f; do
        g=${f##*/}
        program "$f" | subprogram filename="${g%.xy}"
    done' _ {} +
```

If you really need your parameters to be in variables, maybe pass in the suffix as `$0` which isn't used for anything useful here anyway.  It's a bit obscure, but helps avoid the mess you had with double quotes.

```sh
find /path/to -name "*.txt.xy" -exec sh -c '
    for f; do
        g=${f##*/}
        program "$f" | subprogram filename="${g%"$0"}"
    done' ".xy" {} +
```

The above simply trims `g` to the basename which I guess on closer reading you don't want. So pass `/path/to` in `$0` instead, and hardcode .xy inside:

```sh
find /path/to -name "*.txt.xy" -exec sh -c '
    for f; do
        g=${f#"$0"/}
        program "$f" | subprogram filename="${g%.xy}"
    done' "/path/to" {} +
```

or if you really need both to be command-line parameters,

```sh
dir="/path/to"
suffix=".xy"
find "$dir" -name "*.txt$suffix" -exec sh -c '
    suffix=$1
    shift
    for f; do
        g=${f#"$0"/}
        program "$f" | subprogram filename="${g%"$suffix"}"
    done' "$dir" "$suffix" {} +
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but it is worth considering getting all of that logic out of the command line and putting it in a script.  It is much easier to grok `find ... -exec script {} \;`

Comment: If it's reusable I would absolutely put it in a separate script; if it's only useful in this particular script, inlining it avoids polluting your `bin` with random chaff.  Notice also the difference between `find ... -exec {} \;` vs the usually more efficient `find ... -exec {} +` (though with the former the internal script could be simplified).

Answer (score 1):

One reason for the failure, is that the command substitution with `xargs` under double quotes is expanded by the shell even before the former is executed. One way to avoid that would be to do the whole substitution inside the sub-shell created by `sh -c` as

```sh
find "$dir" -name "*.txt.xy" -print0 | 
xargs -0 -I {} sh -c '
  f="{}"
  g="$(echo "$f" | sed -e 's|"'^"${dir}"'"||' -e 's|"'\\"${suffix}"$'"||' )"
  program "$f" | subprogram filename="$g"
'
```